# How to add a handler

Tags: reactjs, quill, react-quill

I have the following code:

```
Banner.modules = {
    toolbar: [
        [{ 'header': '1'}, {'header': '2'}, { 'font': [] }],
        [{size: []}],
        ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike', 'blockquote'],
        [{'list': 'ordered'}, {'list': 'bullet'},
            {'indent': '-1'}, {'indent': '+1'}],
        ['link', 'image', 'video'],
        ['clean']
    ],

    clipboard: {
        // toggle to add extra line breaks when pasting HTML:
        matchVisual: false,
    }
}
```

How can I add a custom handler for `image`? (when an image is uploaded)